# Is there any way to package a maven project to a jar using maven api?

Tags: java, maven

Suppose that I have a maven project located in `/home/admin/projects/maven-sample-project`, I can package the project to a jar using the following command.

```
mvn clean package
```

Now I want to do it with Java and relevant maven-api, is there something like this?

```
MavenProject mavenProject = new MavenProject("/home/admin/projects/maven-sample-project");
mavenProject.clean();
mavenProject.package(jarLocation = "/home/admin/projects/maven-sample-project/target/maven-sample-project-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar");
```

Comment: I think your best bet is to look up Gradle ...

Comment: Why would you like to do that with Java? Apart from that you can use the maven-invoker which offers such things. https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/usage.html

Comment: @khmarbaise Cool, it worked, thanks!

Comment: @moilejter what should a look to Gradle help to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by khmarbaise, maven-invoker is able to solve this problem.

First add the dependency in your `pom.xml` file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-invoker</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then create a new class.

```
import org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MavenRunner {

    public static final String MAVEN_COMMAND_CLEAN = "clean";
    public static final String MAVEN_COMMAND_PACKAGE = "package";

    public static void run(String mavenProjectLocation, List<String> goals) throws MavenInvocationException {
        Invoker invoker = getInvoker(mavenProjectLocation);
        InvocationRequest request = getInvocationRequest(mavenProjectLocation, goals);
        InvocationResult result = invoker.execute(request);
        if ( result.getExitCode() != 0 )
        {
            String exceptionMsgPrefix = String.format("Failed to run maven commands, mavenProjectLocation: %s, goals: %s.", mavenProjectLocation, goals);
            if ( result.getExecutionException() != null )
            {
                throw new MavenInvocationException(exceptionMsgPrefix + "exception: " + result.getExecutionException());
            }
            else
            {
                throw new MavenInvocationException(exceptionMsgPrefix + "exit code: " + result.getExitCode());
            }
        }
    }
    private static Invoker getInvoker(String mavenProjectLocation) {
        Invoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker();
        invoker.setLocalRepositoryDirectory(new File(mavenProjectLocation));
        // replace it with yours
        invoker.setMavenHome(new File("/home/admin/apps/apache-maven-3.5.2"));
        return invoker;
    }
    private static InvocationRequest getInvocationRequest(String mavenProjectLocation, List<String> goals) {
        InvocationRequest request = new DefaultInvocationRequest();
        request.setBaseDirectory(new File(mavenProjectLocation));
        request.setGoals(goals);
        return request;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
String mavenProjectLocation = "/home/admin/projects/maven-sample-project";
List<String> goals = Arrays.asList(MavenRunner.MAVEN_COMMAND_CLEAN, MavenRunner.MAVEN_COMMAND_PACKAGE);
MavenRunner.run(mavenProjectLocation, goals);
```